# How to talk between cross-domain iframes in phantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

We are using phantomJS to test our frontend code, and currently the team is using the hooks on onConsoleMessage() to communicate between cross-domain iframes that are necessary in our project.

Is there a better way to do that?

I don't like the idea of our tests using the console to communicate. They mostly just have to send status flags. I'm pretty sure we are missing something obvious on how phantomJS deals with the iframes and how to inject code on them.